# How to add a toolbar in an empty activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

How can I add toolbar in Android empty activity(its xml is by default constraint layout). I've tried to change the values in styles.xml but none of that works for me and I want a toolbar which will stay in all the activities.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in your xml and use a Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme in your styles.xml.

Comment: If you want to add toolbar in all activity then you can make toolbar layout and include it in whole activity.Second way is Make BaseActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you well:
First you can create toolbar.xml which can look like this depending on how you want it to look:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The you can use the `<include>` tag within every xml file of your activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```